# MySQL Connector Pooling with many async inserts

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, mysql-connector

I was reading about the [MySQL: Using Connector/Net with Connection Pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html).  It is suggested to not use a global `MySqlConnection` object and manually open/close it.  Further, it's suggested to use the `MySqlHelper` instead of working with `MySqlCommand` objects.

So, assuming I have a `CONNECTION_STRING` setup, I could do something like:

```
MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(CONNECTION_STRING,
    @"INSERT INTO `table1` (`col3`,`col4`) VALUES (@col3, @col4 );",
    (new List<MySqlParameter>() {
                new MySqlParameter("@col3", @"another value"),
                new MySqlParameter("@col4", @"some value")    
            }).ToArray()
    );
```

Now, imagine that I make the above call a few thousand times in async parallel tasks (via TPL).

There's some max allowed connections on my MySQL server, and I start to get exceptions thrown claiming the user had exceeded max connections.  I thought the connection pooling was suppose to handle this automatically for me?  Isn't the driver suppose to pool and queue them automatically for me?

I have 1500 max connections allowed currently, and I added this in my connection string:

`Pooling=True;minimumPoolSize=0;maximumpoolsize=100;`

Yet, I still get max connections exceeded.  I need some advice with how to handle many async inserts without exploding this max connections limit.

Comment: Finally found the issue, I guess MySQL has `max_connections` as a server-wide thing (mine is 1500), but also has `max_user_connections` (max connections per MySQL user account) which mine was set to 15.

Comment: You can add your comment as an answer and then accept your own answer after a time period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `max_connections`, the `max_user_connections` is what is important here.  It can be queried for:

```
show variables like 'max_user_connections';
```

To avoid exceeding max connections for your MySQL user you'll need to make sure the `maximumpoolsize` (in the connection string) is set to something lower than `max_user_connections` and that other apps are not opening connections with that same user account whose total could exceed the cap.  So for example, I could set mine to 5 given I have a cap of 15.

Capping this is very common by most hosting services to limit the resources you are using.

Performing a larger batch of queries in a single connection could also be a viable workaround.

In addition, sometimes hosts limit `max_queries_per_hour` and other such variables.